# How to detect if a page is overflowing horizontally with Selenium Driver?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, selenium

I'm using Selenium to load a web page. I need to detect if the page is overflowing horizontally. Unfortunately, `driver.FindElement(By.TagName("html")).Size.Width` always returns the browser width, even if the actual HTML element is overflowing.

Checking for the existence of a horizontal scroll bar would work. Is there anyway to check for that?

Any other ideas?

C# code examples are appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I don't know C#, but the essence of it is perform the following JQuery on the page:

```
$("body").width() >= $(window).width()
```

and cast it to a boolean;

Answer (score 1):

As a update for MrTi answer you can use this C# code:

```
 var js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)webDriver;
 var isOverflowing = js.ExecuteScript("$('body').width() >= $(window).width()");
```

This returns boolean value if window is oveflowing

Comment: Thanks, that led me down the correct path. But this does not work. $('body').width() does not return the actual body width, just the visible part.

Comment: Just to be clear: MCM's solution is in http://stackoverflow.com/a/18922093/334862

Answer (score 1):

This works, no jQuery required.

bool isOver = (bool)js.ExecuteScript("javascript: return document.getElementsByTagName(\"html\")[0].scrollWidth > document.getElementsByTagName(\"html\")[0].clientWidth");